# Получить список пользователей из группы LDAP в Spring Boot

Tags: java, spring-boot, active-directory, ldap

У меня тестовый ldap сервер поднимается вместе со Spring Boot
настройки

```
spring.ldap.embedded.base-dn=dc=javausecase,dc=com
spring.ldap.embedded.ldif=classpath:schema.ldif
spring.ldap.embedded.port=8389
spring.ldap.embedded.url=ldap://localhost:8389/
spring.ldap.embedded.validation.enabled=false
```

содержимое ldif

```
dn: dc=javausecase,dc=com
objectclass: top
objectclass: domain
objectclass: extensibleObject
dc: javausecase

dn: ou=groups,dc=javausecase,dc=com
objectclass: top
objectclass: organizationalUnit
ou: groups

dn: ou=subgroups,ou=groups,dc=javausecase,dc=com
objectclass: top
objectclass: organizationalUnit
ou: subgroups

dn: ou=people,dc=javausecase,dc=com
objectclass: top
objectclass: organizationalUnit
ou: people


dn: cn=one,ou=groups,dc=javausecase,dc=com
cn: one
objectClass: top
objectClass: posixGroup
gidNumber: 1100
description: UNIX systems administrators
memberUID: 111,222

dn: cn=two,ou=groups,dc=javausecase,dc=com
cn: two
objectClass: top
objectClass: posixGroup
gidNumber: 801
description: Network Service Switch Proxy
memberUID: 222

dn: uid=111,ou=people,dc=javausecase,dc=com
objectclass: top
objectclass: person
objectclass: organizationalPerson
objectclass: inetOrgPerson
cn: 111
sn: 111
uid: 111
gidNumber: 111
userPassword: {SHA}fDYHuOYbzxlE6ehQOmYPIfS28/E=

dn: uid=222,ou=people,dc=javausecase,dc=com
objectclass: top
objectclass: person
objectclass: organizationalPerson
objectclass: inetOrgPerson
cn: 222
sn: 222
uid: 222
gidNumber: 222
userPassword: {SHA}fDYHuOYbzxlE6ehQOmYPIfS28/E=
```

я хочу протестировать что удалось положить пользователей по группам.

Как можно проверить что пользователь 111 лежит в группе one а пользователь 222 в группах 111 & 222?

Я написал такой вот запрос

```
List<Attribute> attributes = ldapTemplate.search(
                query().where("objectclass").is("posixGroup"),
                new AttributesMapper<Attribute>() {
                    public Attribute mapFromAttributes(Attributes attrs)
                            throws NamingException {
                        return attrs.get("cn");
                    }
                });
```

он возвращает 2 атрибута one и two, но как мне вытащить дальше из этих атрибутов содержимое memberUID

я не совсем понимаю.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Из [документации](https://docs.spring.io/spring-ldap/docs/current/reference/#spring-ldap-basic-usage) видим, что нужно реализовать свой класс, отражающий юзера в системе LDAP и маппер для этого класса.

Делаем.

```
public class LdapPerson {
   private String fullName;
   private String lastName;
   private String memberUID;

   //getters & setters here
}

public List<LdapPerson> getPersons(String name) {
   SearchControls sc = new SearchControls();
   sc.setSearchScope(SearchControls.SUBTREE_SCOPE);
   sc.setReturningAttributes(new String[]{"cn", "sn", "memberUID"});
   String filter = "(&(objectclass=posixGroup)(cn=" + name + "))";

   List<LdapPerson> persons = ldapTemplate.search(new LdapName(""), filter, sc, new PersonAttributesMapper());
   return persons;
}

private class PersonAttributesMapper implements AttributesMapper<LdapPerson> {
   LdapPerson person = new LdapPerson();

   Attribute fullName = attrs.get("cn");
   if (fullName != null) {
      person.setFullName = (String) fullName.get();
   }

   Attribute lastName = attrs.get("sn");
   if (lastName != null) {
      person.setLastName = (String) lastName.get();
   }

   Attribute memberUID = attrs.get("memberUID");
   if (memberUID != null) {
      person.setMemberUID = (String) memberUID.get();
   }

   return person;
}
```

Как-то так.

Если не нужна сущность LDAP, тогда там в документации ниже есть пример как построить конкретный запрос, чтобы вытащить нужную инфу через `LdapQuery`.